# preg_replace remove ' from string

Tags: php

How to use an extra ' in `preg_replace`?

I have this code:

```
$bedrijf = preg_replace('/OR ds.bedrijf LIKE /', '', $bedrijf, 1);
```

To remove `OR ds.bedrijf LIKE` but I need to remove `OR ds.bedrijf LIKE'`

Any suggestions?

Comment: try `'/OR ds.bedrijf LIKE\' /'`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single. You don't really need a regexp for that.

Comment: If you're gluing SQL queries together with this - there are better solutions.

Comment: If this is for SQL, that "." will match any character...Including a dot, but it could match other things as well. If you don't need that "." to match "any" character, then you should consider using str_replace instead. Regular expressions are bad for performance, and you shouldn't get into the habit of using them when a simple string replace will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the quote with a backslash or use double-quotes.

In your case :

```
'/OR ds.bedrijf LIKE\' /'
```

or with double-quotes

```
"/OR ds.bedrijf LIKE' /"
```

But if your goal is only to remove parts of a string, [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is a much more simple solution.